# Gtk-WARNING Could not find signal handler on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, gtk, handler, signals, glade

I'm building an interface using glade and gtk programming on c using netbeans. I've set up my project following [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/articles/netbeanscdevelopment/). I even added libgmodule2-0.so and libglib2-0.so to the linker options of netbeans. When I run i get the warning Gtk-WARNING Could not find signal handle. When I close the mainwindow nothing happens (this is where my signal should be caught)

If I compile my program like this (not using netbeans)

```
gcc -o tut main.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0)
```

it works fine. When I close the mainwindow it closes.

I like using IDEs because all the features I get (specially debugging). Any suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that adding `libgmodule2-0.so` and `libglib2-0.so` to the linker options is not enough. Run the command `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0` in your terminal and see what it says. Add any directories listed with `-I` to the include directories of your NetBeans project, and add any other flags to the C compiler options.

Then run `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0` in your terminal and add anything listed there to the linker options.

Comment: that worked. I was following a tutorial how to set up netbeans with gtk and they didn't added all libs and includes pkg-config showed. Thx

Comment: For the record adding "gmodule-2.0", took care of the whines for clang and gtk+3.0, thanks!  My usage: `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0`